# Is a CNAME record public

Tags: dns, github-pages, cname

For example, I have a GitHub Pages site with a custom domain.
Here are the dns records for the domain:
[image]
Is this CNAME record public?
Or is there a way for someone to determine the GitHub Pages url, `ajzbc.github.io`, from my custom domain `ajzbc.com`

To clarify, is there for example a command I could run that would output the CNAME?

Thanks

Comment: If by public you mean accessible by the public, yes it is.

Comment: @Tachyon How would someone see this record? Something like `dig ajzbc.com`?

Comment: Depending on what OS you're on you can do it in different ways. For instance on Windows you can open cmd type in, `nslookup` then `type=CNAME` then `ajzbc.com` and hit enter and it should return all the CNAME records for that domain.

Comment: @Tachyon I have tried that before. Got this error `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: That would then be an underlying issue with either your connection to your DNS provider or the provider itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For main domain : `dig ajzbc.com`

For www subdomain : `dig www.ajzbc.com`

Comment: only getting the cname when doing `dig www.ajzbc.com` weird but thanks

Comment: It's normal, ajzbc.com has only A records, and www subdomain uses CNAME.

Answer (score 1):

```
dbajic@ ~ $ dig www.ajzbc.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.ajzbc.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62752
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ajzbc.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ajzbc.com.      1798    IN  CNAME   ajzbc.github.io.
ajzbc.github.io.    3599    IN  A   185.199.109.153
ajzbc.github.io.    3599    IN  A   185.199.108.153
ajzbc.github.io.    3599    IN  A   185.199.110.153
ajzbc.github.io.    3599    IN  A   185.199.111.153

;; Query time: 51 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 26 10:27:47 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135

dbajic@ ~ $
```